# Ant not working with Jenkins within a Docker container

Tags: jenkins, docker, ant

I want to have my Jenkins CI in a Docker container.

I've pulled the Jenkins Docker image and started it [following the documentation](https://hub.docker.com/_/jenkins/):

```
sudo docker run -p 8080:8080 -p 50000:50000 -v /var/jenkins_home:/var/jenkins_home jenkins
```

Jenkins is started okay, I configure the job for the project using Ant as build tool.

When I run the job, Jenkins throws the following error regarding to Ant (regardless the configured build target):

> ERROR: command execution failed.Maybe you need to configure the job to
>   choose one of your Ant installations?

But, if I go to the workspace directory of the build (`/var/jenkins_home/workspace/my_job/`) and execute the same target, I get no error:

```
ant clean
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you run your build on master node? If so - you probably don't have `ant` *inside* the container. You can try it running `docker exec your_jenkins_container_name ant --version`. Unfortunately I am not sure I can suggest you a proper way in your case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @izzekil has pointed, Ant was not installed inside the container, but only in the host machine.

It has been enough to install Ant in the container (running with `root` user):

```
sudo docker run -p 8080:8080 -p 50000:50000 -v /var/jenkins_home:/var/jenkins_home -u root jenkins
```

And then:

```
sudo docker exec <container_id> apt-get update
sudo docker exec <container_id> apt-get install ant -y
```

Comment: Is this best practice to run Jenkins as root user?  Can that user ever get outside the container?

Comment: It is not best practice. Ideally you would run Jenkins as non root, maybe just using the official https://hub.docker.com/_/jenkins/ image which already does so, and then use external workers which have ant installed to do the builds. Those workers, if they are also containers either in docker, kubernetes, or some other system, can be created from images which have ant installed and should also not need to run as root. If you're using kubernetes, the official https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/jenkins (for now) helm chart can be used for this.